# Render a function with onError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, render

I have this object that I want to render when an error occurs while running a grapqhl query (on Apollo's onError):

```
export const ErrorContainer: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  console.log('container running')
  return (
    <View style={styles.errorView}>
    <Text style={styles.errorText}>Unable to Load Friends</Text>
  </View>
  );
};
```

Now on my main screen, I tried this:

```
const { data, error } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
  onCompleted: () => {
    //setUserData(data)
  },
  onError: ErrorContainer
  },
});
```

I also tried this:

```
{error && <ErrorContainer />}
```

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeView}>
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Text
          style={styles.backText}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
          Zurück
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.listHolder}>
        {data && 
          <FlatList
            data={data.me.friends}
            horizontal={false}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Friend
                friend={item}
                //onDeleteFriend={onDeleteFriend}
                originatorId={data.me.id}
              />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            ListEmptyComponent={NoFriendsContainer}
          />
            }
            {error && ErrorContainer}
        </View>
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

but although I see the console logs, i dont see the actual content of the ErrorContainer. How else should I call the component?

Comment: What is `useGetMyProfileQuery`? What does it return? Looks like a custom hook?

Comment: Yes, it's a custom graphql hook (react-apollos). the onError property works. I have checked with logs. so problem Is with how I am calling the ErrorContainer component @ChrisG

Comment: if,  as you say, you see `console.log('container running')` then the problem is in styles

Comment: but I was using the same styling that I used when the function was on the same page. It doesn't work from a different page even tho styling is same. Currently trying ```onError: 
      ErrorContainer``` and it gives the log @Rostyslav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing component as a callback to the hook as here `onError: ErrorContainer` makes no sense. Despite, component is a function, passing it as a callback will not magically render it.

You have to render it in the template. Like you did above `{error && <ErrorContainer />}`

Just try to add additional state to your screen

```
const [isErrorVisible, setErrorVisible] = useState(false);
```

And then set it in the callback where you passed component before

```
const { data, error } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
  onCompleted: () => {
    //setUserData(data)
  },
  onError: () => {
    setErrorVisible(true); // callback now instead of ErrorContainer
  }
});
```

And then use it in your template

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeView}>
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Text
          style={styles.backText}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
          Zurück
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.listHolder}>
        {data && 
          <FlatList
            data={data.me.friends}
            horizontal={false}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Friend
                friend={item}
                //onDeleteFriend={onDeleteFriend}
                originatorId={data.me.id}
              />
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            ListEmptyComponent={NoFriendsContainer}
          />
         }
         {/* here using the flag and rendering the component in template */}
         {isErrorVisible && <ErrorContainer />}
        </View>
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Comment: had already tried this but I guess it was just. styling after all